# Сколько может быть максимально задач в Cron?

Tags: cron

Сколько может быть максимально задач в Cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сколько захочешь! :)

Пока система сможет это все обрабатывать!

Comment: тоже хочу так отвечать и зеленые галки получать!!))

Comment: Ну совсем сколько захочешь. В какой то момент на диске закончиться место и кронтаб файл не будет куда записывать...